# Create moment Object from UTC string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, utc

I'm getting from my webservice an UTC date String such as the following : 
`"2015-06-06T12:30:12Z"`

I need to display it following these 2 rules :

1. If date < 1 week, display it like : 3 days ago or 23 mins ago....
2. If date > 1 week, display the date `YYYY-DD-MM`

Now I'm trying to build a moment object but seems to be returning something weird :

```
var sDate = "2015-06-06T12:30:12Z";
var momentDate = moment(sDate);
var fromNow = momentDate.fromNow();
console.log("momentDate : " + momentDate);    // 1433593812000
console.log("fromNow : " + fromNow);    // 11å°æ™‚å‰
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: That's strange, but I executed your code (as is) in JsFiddle and everything seems to be fine:
[Log] momentDate : 1433593812000
[Log] fromNow : 11 hours ago
It could be an issue with page or machine character sets.

Comment: @sviklim : Thanks. Sorry just figured out that I was using `moment-with-locale.js`... doesn't it wrap `moment.js` ?

Comment: sorry, I have no experience with `moment-with-locale.js`; I used to work with raw library version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just hitting a bug, already logged as [#2367](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2367).

Stated very simply, it's using the last locale loaded ("zh-tw"), rather than defaulting to English.

Simply call add the following line after you load moment but before you use it anywhere.

```
moment.locale('en');
```

This sets the language back to English.

That explains the output of the `fromNow` string.  The other output is because you concatenated the moment object directly with another string, which implicitly calls `.valueOf()`, which returns the UTC-based timestamp in milliseconds.  You should instead use `.format()`, perhaps with an argument such as `.format("YYYY-MM-DD")` - if that's the output format you would like to see.