# moment.js converts milliseconds into japanese date

Tags: javascript, date, datatables, momentjs

I am trying to convert a date from milliseconds to `ddd Do MMMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss` using moment.js. The data is retrieved from a db which gives as result milliseconds

MySQL table value`2012-12-11 09:24:15`
Json value `1355217855000`

Datatable Render

```
render: function (data) {
    return moment(data).format('ddd Do MMMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss');
}
```

I would expect something like 
`Tue 11th Dec 2012, 09:24:15`
but my result is `週二 11日 十二月 2012, 09:24:15`

Any reason why?

**EDIT**

I am using moment-with-locales.js

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30744085/634824

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `moment.locale('en');` to your script, [JSFiddles here](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/369shdep/)

```
moment.locale('en');
var d = moment('2012-12-11 09:24:15').format('ddd Do MMMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss');
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain why moment is set as default to japanese?? How can I change the default language?? Where should I paste the following line: `moment.locale("en").format('LLL');`